# Using the Internal Storage - Android - Deleting Cache Files

Tags: android, caching, storage, internal

I am downloading images and then saving them to the internal memory. This has a result the cache of the app to grow very quickly.

As it is suggested here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

*When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete these cache files to recover space. However, you should not rely on the system to clean up these files for you. You should always maintain the cache files yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space consumed, such as 1MB*

My question is what will happen if the cache gets too big, for example now is around 20mb and is still growing.

I thought that I should follow the guidelines and delete them each time my app starts if internet connection is available.

```
 String[] allFiles =  fileList();

 Log.e(TAG, "allFiles.length: " + allFiles.length);


 for(int k=0; k<allFiles.length; k++)
 {
 Log.e(TAG, "allFiles [ " +k+"]: "+allFiles[k]);

 }
```

However, this code always return zero files. If i try to access a specific image I can easily retrieve it from the internal memory. Why this code cannot return an array with all my images??

What is the right approach to follow for the internal memory..

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Comment: Your entire filename retrieval logic is inside `fileList()` which you didn't include. There's no way for us to know why this isn't working if you don't post that code.

Comment: I can access each image(filename) individually with no problem! the problem is when I want to get the list of all files in internal memory as suggested in the link above. the method above always returns zero!

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. I didn't know `fileList()` was on Context. I wouldn't bother with that anyway. If you're storing in the folder from `getCacheDir` then just use `getCacheDir().listFiles()`.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else asked a similar question just yesterday. [Here's my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219999/deleting-external-cache-directory-periodically/8220075#8220075) to that one. Some relevant key points of it though is that you can limit the whole cache size and/or limit the amount of time you keep a file in your cache and that should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The point is how do I access those files and place the ttl without using a txt that stores the hashing of the url? and how should I limit the size. we are always talking about internal memory!!

Comment: As I commented on your main post, there's no way to know what's wrong with your code if you don't post the relevant lines... As far as limiting the size, you could do something like use LruCache, overriding the sizeOf method to return the size of the cached file, and then delete the file on eviction from the cache. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Comment: I am sorry but this is complete irrelevant of what I am asking...My problem is that with the code above the files are not listed even if it exist as suggested in the android developer site. Thank you anyway for your answers